# Visual Studio 2019 IIS Express infinite waiting

Tags: c#, iis-express, visual-studio-2019

I migrated from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 and now, when I run my AspNet Core application with IIS Express, i receive an infinite waiting for site page.
Browser is opened but page is loading forever.

Can anyone help me understanding the reason?

With VS2017 that problem never happened.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Bye

Update:
As suggested by JayMee I checked my logs.
I've no breakpoints and, if I pause application, it doesn't show me what's doing...seems that is blocked before to run completely the site.

In My output windows, into Asp-NetCore output, it shows the following:

Now listening on: http://localhost:42848
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44359/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 DEBUG http://localhost:44360/  0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 795.63ms 200

Finally I've no significant Event Viewer logs information regarding IIS Express.

Comment: Check you don't have any breakpoints hit. Check your output window. Check windows event logs. If no clearer, hit 'pause' on your debugging tools and see what it's doing..

Comment: Hi JayMee, I updated my question answering your suggestions...

Comment: +1 for adding detail. Can you put a breakpoint in whatever action you're hitting first? See if it hits that? If not, place it even earlier (startup.cs) and see if it hits that. You basically need to find out where it's hanging.

Comment: Hi JayMee, I tried to put a some breakpoints into startup class and into first called controller. Sometimes it hits them but sometimes doesn't.
Retrying many times very rarely debug started but is a strange behaviour.
I tried to deactivate the antivirus installed on my machine and debug always starts. But I can't keep the antivirus turned off...is possible that antivirus causes this problem. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi guys,the problem has never been solved...can anyone help me pleeease !!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the root cause but have been affected the last few weeks (v16.8.5) and managed to work around

- kill the iisexpress process

If no juice:

- delete the `.vs` folder in the solution root

The combination of the 2 has always worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions.
The problem has been solved contacting our system administrators and changing some parameters to the Antivirus software...it was the problem.

Now all is working fine.

Comment: I still don't get why antiviruses still exist in 2021 :P